# Serialize without attribute or deserialize with attribute override?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class like this:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Entry")]
    public int Entry { get { return this.Id; } set { this.Id = value; } }
}
```

And I don't want to serialize the `Entry` attribute but still want to be able to deserialize it from files that have said attribute.

If I either set `XmlIgnore` it will not read during deserialization and if I don't it will write both `Entry` and `Id` to my serialized file which I don't want.

**I know I could generate a secondary class with excludes Entry altogether and use that specific one for serializing, but I grew curious if there is a way to make so it will not serialize the Id or it will deserialize the `Entry` into the `Id` attribute instead?**

*I am open to other suggestions as well...*

EDIT:

Also tried using `XmlIgnoreAttribute` as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

With true on my serialization and false on my deserialization, but didn't work.

---

Just to further clarify the issue, how the XML's are formatted is not something I control and what I am doing is merely a 3rd party application that will read those files and save them back. To me the `Entry` attribute is redundant and unneeded hence why I save it to the Id as they are the same, however there are many elements with no `Id` and instead they have the `Entry`, once my application is used to read and re-save the file it removes the `Entry` and saves it as `Id` instead.

Also to serialize and deserialize it I have to inject the root element name:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new XmlRootAttribute(root));
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file))
{
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Because the root name will differ from file to file I have to inject it.

Comment: Entry is an int ... not nullable type, so every single object will have this property defined.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar I can make it nullable there but in either case it will make fields that have Entry contain both, Id=... Entry=...

Comment: I gave you an example on how to control serialization... You now see how its done, so its up to you to define the boolean conditions that turn on or off the fields... but consider that mixing non nullables with ShouldSerializeXXX is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to steer away from non nullable types in order to do that...

Just consider the small change on the code:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Entry")]
    public string Entry { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can tell the serializer that you want to exclude certain field in the serialization process, by adding a member function to the class called ShouldSerializeXYZ() where XYZ is the name of the field you want to control.

In this case, the function needed would look like:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeEntry()
{
    // Here you complete control on when to include the field
    // As a simple example I excluded the field if its empty
    // But you can make more complex conditions 
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Entry);
}
```

You can have one method per each property, so in theory you could also add a ShouldSerialize for Name, and Id but on my experience, this technique will not work with non nullable types.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you implement your own custom XML serialize/deserialize logic. You can get more information about how to do that on this link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474453/How-to-customize-XML-serialization

Comment: All I need is a way to exclude that one attribute on serialization and creating my own logic seems way too much for just that.